# Hibernate mapping OneToOne without column and on non-primary key

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, h2

I've simplified my model but i've a model like :

```
class Process {
    private int idProcess;
}

class Step {
    private int idStep;
}

class Action {
    private int idAction;
}

class Option {
    private int idOption;
    private int idObject;
    private TypeOption type;
}

enum typeOption {
    PROCESS, STEP, ACTION
}
```

This model was choosen because we can have options on many types, and this field was used only to add "things" that we have forgotten for last version of the software. So can have Options on anything.

I want to add a mapping between source objects and options like :

```
class Process {
    private int idProcess;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(?)
    private Option option;
}
```

but i want a sql like :

```
table Process {idProcess}
table Options {idOption, idObject, type}
```

=> I don't want a column "idOption" into Process table, and i don't want that Hibernate add a foreign key on idObject because the foreign key isn't idObject but {idObject, type}

So i want that hibernate do :

```
SELECT p.idProcess, o.idOption FROM Process p, Option o WHERE o.idObject = Process.idProcess AND o.type = "PROCESS";
```

How can i do it?

Remarks :

- I use Oracle DB in production but H2 for tests
- H2 schema is auto-generated by hibernate (for tests) but Oracle schema was generated by an external software